# Problema con la actualización de la posición de columna de un dataGridView

Tags: c#, datatable, datagrid

Resulta que cargo datos a un dataGridView, con columnas adicionalmente insertadas(CheckBoxColumn, button) en determinadas posiciones.

Pero cuando voy al evento CellContentClick, me muestra los valores de las celdas con distinta posición que la columna realmente debería tener.

Explicaré con mas Detalle. Tengo el evento Load que carga los datos en el DataGridView:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   cargarDocElectronicosEmitidos();
        //cargarDocElectronicosEmitidos();

    }
```

La función de carga:

```
 private void cargarDocElectronicosEmitidos(){
       dtgdocumentosXML.Columns.Clear();               
            DataTable dt_tickets = new DataTable();
            dt_tickets.Clear();
  String sql = "SELECT ...";
            conexion.conectar();
            MySqlDataAdapter datos = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion.con);
            datos.Fill(dt_tickets);
            var source = new BindingSource();
            source.DataSource = dt_tickets;
            dtgdocumentosXML.DataSource = source;
            dtgdocumentosXML.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            dtgdocumentosXML.Columns[7].Visible = false;

            DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            dtgdocumentosXML.Columns.Insert(8, btn);

            btn.HeaderText = "Enviado SII?";
            btn.Text = "Verificar";
            btn.Name = "btn_verificar";
            btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

            dtgdocumentosXML.AllowUserToAddRows = false;// dtgdocumentosXML.Rows.Remove(dtgdocumentosXML.Rows[dtgdocumentosXML.Rows.Count - 1]);       
        //dtgdocumentosXML.ResetBindings();
        //dtgdocumentosXML.Refresh();
        //dtgdocumentosXML.Parent.Refresh();
}
```

El problema se detecta cuando presiono el boton verificar del datagridview, voy al evento grilla_CellContentClick.

```
  private void grilla_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {           
            var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;              
            string numero= grilla.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Problema es el siguiente:
El valor de numero que se muestra es el valor del boton verificar y no del contenido de la primera columna 0 como se espera. Pero cuando cambio datos con filtros, y llamando a cargarDocElectronicosEmitidos nuevamente, ahí que se corrige y muestra el contenido bien de la columna correspondiente para el evento _CellContentClick.

La forma que se me soluciona es llamar a la funcion dos veces en el load, pero no es la idea.
Espero una solución deseada por favor

Comment: Puedes usar .Cells["NombreDeColumna"] si es que el nombre de la columna no cambia o lo sabes siempre de antemano para obtener el valor correspondiente en lugar de usar el indice. Saludos

Comment: La consulta sql cuantas columnas te devuelve?

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví gracias a @Jesus Rodríguez, colocando el nombre de la columna en vez la posición .Cells["NombreDeColumna"]